# Eclipse/PyDev: Open Interactive console when program starts

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I find myself opening the interactive shell nearly every time I launch Eclipse. To save my lazy self a few extra clicks every day, I started wonder: **is there is a way to get an interactive console to open automatically on start-up of Eclipse/PyDev?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not... please enter a feature request for that (it should be relatively straightforward adding a preference where you can choose an interpreter which would be used to open an interactive console when you open Eclipse).